# What's the point of 1-norm matrix estimation? Why not brute force?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Calculating (brute-force) 1-norm of a square matrix should take $O(n^2)$ operations, with a small factor involved. Apparently, there is an algorithm ([link](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0895479899356080)) for estimating 1-norm that takes $O(n^2 t)$ operations.

I'm a complete outsider to this field, but what's the gain here? I mean, why wait longer when you can gain exact results in less time? Even if $t$ is small, why waste the same amount of time for less precise result.

My only guess is that the linked estimation algorithm calculates (as a side effect) not only 1-norm, but also some other useful value. If so, is there any reason why would one use this estimation algorithm (or for that matter, any other 1-norm estimation algorithm within the same complexity class) if one is not interested in that other value?

Comment: The paper cited, on p.1189, says the algorithm takes $O(nt^2)$ operations.  This is much better than $O(n^2)$ since $t\ll n$.

Comment: They are referring to specific operations when they say that, not to the whole algortihm.